# modelsummaryのmodelplot()を使って文字化けしない図をpdfで出力するためにはどうすればよいですか？

Tags: r, tidyverse

R Markdownを使ってpdf文書を作成しています。
[modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/index.html)パッケージに含まれる`modelplot()`関数を使ってモデルの推定値と標準誤差を図で示したいですが、図の凡例に日本語が含まれる場合、文字化けを起こします。[公式のドキュメント](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelplot.html)では、日本語を扱う方法は触れられていませんでした。この問題を解決するためにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
サンプルデータを使って再現した図とコードを次に示します。

```
model <- 
  list(
  `モデル1` = lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars),
  `モデル2` = lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
  )

modelplot(model)
```

また、本文の日本語のタイプセットのために設定しているyamlの基本的な構成を次に示します。

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    dev: cairo_pdf
    latex_engine: xelatex
documentclass: bxjsarticle
classoption: xelatex,ja=standard,a4paper,jafont=ms
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{zxjatype}
```

また、ggplot2で図を出力するために以下のような設定を記述しています。
この設定を含めた場合、ggplot2を使用した図は文字化けせずに出力されますが、`modelplot()`を使用した場合だけ文字化けします。

```
library(fontregisterer)
library(systemfonts)
family_sans <- "MS Gothic" 
family_serif <- "MS Mincho" 
theme_set(
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = family_serif, face = "plain"),
    title = element_text(face = "plain"),
    axis.title = element_text(face = "plain"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "plain"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(face = "plain")
  )
)
```

[image: モデル]

Comment: 回答とは直接関係ないですが, bxjsarticle にその classoption を設定した場合, header-includes に zxjatype を読み込む命令を書かかなくても大丈夫です (自動で読み込まれます)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theme()` 関数で `legend.text` を設定して `modelplot(model)` に追加してみてはどうでしょうか。

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(modelsummary)

model <- 
  list(
  `モデル1` = lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars),
  `モデル2` = lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
  )

family_serif <- "MS Mincho"
p <- modelplot(model) + theme(legend.text = element_text(family=family_serif))
ggsave(file="model.pdf", device=cairo_pdf, p)
```

[image: modelplot]

Comment: 私の環境では質問者のコードでも文字化けが発生しないので, もしかするとパッケージのバージョンが絡んでいるかもしれません (R: 4.0.5, ggplot2: v3.3.5, ggthemes: v4.2.4, modelsummary: v0.9.1)

Comment: modelsummaryのバージョンが古かったので更新しましたが文字化けは直りませんでした。しかし @metropolis さんの方法で解決しました。